# MVC3 + MongoDB Architecture: Store models directly to database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, model, viewmodel

I am currently developing a mvc3 application using mongodb. I am quite unsure on how i shall build the architecture. E.g. my app has a page used for managing the user profile for a registered user (like name, email, some attributes exposed inside enum-comboboxes). Hence i have a ManageProfileModel.cs with all properties to manage. What's the proper way to use the data with mongodb? Shall i store the ManageProfileModel data inside mongodb or do i have to add an additional layer containing domain classes like User.cs, Invoice.cs, ... and store these objects inside mongodb (these objects are being used in the models created)?

I am asking because a model for managing a user profile does not necessarily resemble a user (domain) object. My first approach is to store directly my (view)models inside mongodb. I am not sure if its that easy to get my (consistent) data at a later point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would store the models directly in Mongo as-is for most of your data. I'm sure you know this already, but Mongo focuses on denormalization, and so it's different than traditional relational databases that want you to normalize your data.

So for a profile, you might have a user, a set of invoices, a set of addresses etc. As you decide your data models, I would suggest the following:

1. Consider your UI. If you need user + profile + invoices, go ahead and make a document like that. Makes your life a lot easier.
2. Don't be afraid to have repeated information stored.
3. You will constantly be wondering if you should embed a document (adding addresses to user) or link to a document (put a list of references in an array referencing invoices). The rule I've heard that I think is good: If the data is constantly changing, make a link/reference. If it's immutable or slowly changing, embed it.
4. If your document will grow a lot over time, considering breaking it up. Mongo has to move your document in memory if it grows too big.